# cannot convert ‘char* (*)[51]’ to ‘char** (*)[51]’

Tags: parameter-passing

I have this array declared

```
char*          fields[100][51];
```

I have this function declared

```
int GetAllParts(char* fields[][51])
{
...
}
```

I call the function with

```
NumChoices=GetAllParts(fields)
```

I get this compile error

> cannot convert ‘char* (*)[51]’ to ‘char** (*)[51]’ for argument ‘1’ 
>   to ‘int GetAllParts(char** (*)[51])

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: That function call shouldn't give that error with the array as you are showing. Are you sure this is what your program looks like? There's not much context here. Double check your source.

Comment: Either true code is not `int GetAllParts(char* fields[][51])` or compiler broke.  Perhaps there is a conflicting declaration of the function someplace else?